# Can I check to see if CoInitialize has been called or not?

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-xe2, ado

In a multi-threaded environment with ADO database connections, I would like to know if CoInitialize has been called or not. How would I go about checking this?

Comment: @KenWhite - don't forget that a thread's constructor is called in a different thread's context, destructor usually too. So these calls will be called in a wrong context.

Comment: @Serg: Yep, you're right. Should be called in `Execute` and `OnTerminate` of the thread itself instead, or a `try..finally` block in `Execute`.

Comment: Yes this check will be inside the thread in which I need to check.

Comment: Why can't you keep track of whether or not you initialized com? Surely you ought to be able to manage those details.

Comment: Actually I already am, this is more for debugging purposes.

Comment: Note: New continued question asking how to identify how many levels in `CoInitialize` has been called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543496/how-to-identify-how-many-levels-of-coinitialize-have-been-called

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally you should not do this check and just call `CoInitialize`/`CoUnInitialize` pair. Still you can do it like this:

```
function IsCoInitialized: Boolean;
var
  HR: HResult;

begin
  HR:= CoInitialize(nil);
  Result:= (HR and $80000000 = 0) and (HR <> S_OK);
  if (HR and $80000000 = 0) then CoUnInitialize;
end;
```

---

There is no problem if you call `CoInitialize` more than once in a thread. The first call should return `S_OK`, all subsequent calls should return `S_FALSE`. All these calls are considered successful and should be paired by `CoUnInitialize` calls. If you called `CoInitialize` n times in a thread, only the last n-th `CoUnInitialize` call closes COM.

Comment: @Serg, now I'm looking at the `CO_E_ALREADYINITIALIZED = HRESULT($800401F1)` constant defined in my Delphi 2009 `Windows.pas` unit with comment `CoInitialize has already been called.` and wondering what is that constant for. Have you seen or met this before ? Isn't that what returns the subsequent `CoInitialize` function call (can't verify this now) ?

Comment: @TLama - I guess `CO_E_ALREADYINITIALIZED` is never returned by `CoInitialize`, it is specific to other COM functions.

Comment: So you mean if I called `CoInitialize()` `n` times, and called `CoUninitialize()` `n-1` times, then COM will still be open for that thread?